# How to make Questions not repeat itself

Tags: java, arrays, random, drjava

So i am making a Who Wants to be an millionaire game code and i have everything working perfectly. But sometimes questions will repeat themselves, and it does not make for a good game if you ended up getting the same Question twice. I would appreciate all and any help.

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
public class MillionaireGame {


  public static void main(String[] args) { 


        // gets the users name
        Scanner kbreader = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Hello welcome to Wants to Be A Millionaire, Can i get your name please.");
        String name;
        name=kbreader.next();

        // introduce the host and have the host explain the rules
        System.out.println("Welcome again " + name +" I am your host Antonio. i'll be here with you while you play.");
        System.out.println("I am here to explain the rules to you and be a host. let me tell you the rules of the game.");
        System.out.println("We will ask you a series of questions 14 in total and you win money if you get the questions right");
        System.out.println("There two check points $10000 and $320000. if you lose or quit before $10000 you go home empty handed.");
        System.out.println("If you lose or quit after the $10000 question but before the $320000 you go home with $10000.");
        System.out.println("If you lose or quit after the $320000 question but before the $1000000 you go home with $320000.");
        System.out.println("Let the games being computer first question please.");

        //The string array is to how the possible question one
        String question1[]={"What year did world war 2 end in",
                "The canadian great depression started in",
                "Sir John A Mcdonald last term started in",
                "Canada became its own contruy in",};

        //these string arrays are to keep the asnswer for the questions and give the other options
        String answer1[]={"1945","1929","1891","1867",};
        String options1[]={"1943","1904","1886","1782","1748","1764","1897","1823","1899","1858","1900","1909",};

        String question2[]={"What is the capital of Yukon",
                "What is the capital of Northwest Territories",
                "Where is Parliament Hill",
                "_________ is called No Fun City "};

        String answer2[]={"Whitehorse","Yellowknife","Ottawa","Vancouver"};
        String options2[]={"London","Kingston","Saint John","Winnipeg","Victoria","Edmonton","Calgary","Montreal"};

        //The string array is to how the possible question one
        String question3[]={"Which country has the most people",
                "Which country invented football(soccer)",
                "Which country started World War one",
                "Which country has the largest debt",};

        //these string arrays are to keep the asnswer for the questions and give the other options
        String answer3[]={"China","England","Austria-Hungary","United States",};
        String options3[]={"Canada","India","Japan","Germany","Russia","Brazil","France","Mexio","Egypt","Jamaica","Italy","Austria",};

        //The string array is to how the possible question one
        String question4[]={"To which Super-Hero was With great power comes Great Responsibility said to",
                "Which Super-Hero takes the role of Captain America after he died",
                "What is the name of the Acher on the Avengers",
                "Other than Captian America, Chris Evans acted as which Super-Hero",};

        //these string arrays are to keep the asnswer for the questions and give the other options
        String answer4[]={"Spider-Man","Winter Soldier","Hawkeye","Human Torch",};
        String options4[]={"Super-Man","Batman","Flash","Iron Man","Hulk","Thor","DareDevil","Green Arrow","QuickSliver","Super-Girl","Nova","StarLord",};

        //This int array is to hold the prices for the money and keep count of it as the play gets higher
        int money[]={0,1000,2000,3000,5000,10000,20000,40000,80000,160000,320000,640000,1250000,2500000,5000000,10000000};

        //This string array is to talk to the user and give them the next question
        String com1[]={"Antonio: Coumpter what is next question",
                "Antonio: Next question please",
                "Antonio: Are you ready for the next question",
                "Antonio : Next question Please"};

        String com2[]={"Antonio: We will tell you what the answer was",
                "Antonio: Since you quit you get to know the answer",
                "Antonio: Since you're dying to know what the answer was",
                "Antonio: The computer will show you the answer"};

        //this random is to get pick which questions answers and options are printed
        Random r= new Random();
        int qch,ra,rq=0,ans=0,nextq=0,m=1,bal=0;
        do{
        System.out.println("\033"); 
        qch=r.nextInt(4);
        int len1=options1.length;
        int len2=options2.length;
        int len3=options3.length;
        int len4=options4.length;
        System.out.println("\nyou have won= "+money[bal]+"\n");
        System.out.println("\n\tThis question is for $"+money[m]+"\n");        

        //if statements to matcht he answer with the question even after it was randomize
        //the if statements also print out the options
        if(qch==0)
        {
            rq=r.nextInt(4);
            System.out.println(question1[rq]);
            ra=r.nextInt(4);
            if(ra==0)
            {
                System.out.println(answer1[rq]);
                for(int i=0;i<3;i++)
                System.out.println(options1[r.nextInt(len1)]);
                ans=1;
            }
            if(ra==1)
            {
                System.out.println(options1[r.nextInt(len1)]);
                System.out.println(answer1[rq]);
                for(int i=0;i<2;i++)
                System.out.println(options1[r.nextInt(len1)]);
                ans=2;
            }
            if(ra==2)
            {
                for(int i=0;i<2;i++)
                System.out.println(options1[r.nextInt(len1)]);
                System.out.println(answer1[rq]);
                System.out.println(options1[r.nextInt(len1)]);
                ans=3;
            }
            if(ra==3)
            {
                for(int i=0;i<3;i++)
                System.out.println(options1[r.nextInt(len1)]);
                System.out.println(answer1[rq]);
                ans=4;
            }   

        }
        if(qch==1)
        {
            rq=r.nextInt(4);
            System.out.println(question2[rq]);
            ra=r.nextInt(4);
            if(ra==0)
            {
                System.out.println(answer2[rq]);
                for(int i=0;i<3;i++)
                System.out.println(options2[r.nextInt(len2)]);
                ans=1;
            }
            if(ra==1)
            {
                System.out.println(options2[r.nextInt(len2)]);
                System.out.println(answer2[rq]);
                for(int i=0;i<2;i++)
                System.out.println(options2[r.nextInt(len2)]);
                ans=2;
            }
            if(ra==2)
            {
                for(int i=0;i<2;i++)
                System.out.println(options2[r.nextInt(len2)]);
                System.out.println(answer2[rq]);
                System.out.println(options2[r.nextInt(len2)]);
                ans=3;
            }
            if(ra==3)
            {
                for(int i=0;i<3;i++)
                System.out.println(options2[r.nextInt(len2)]);
                System.out.println(answer2[rq]);
                ans=4;
            }   

        }
        if(qch==2)
        {
            rq=r.nextInt(4);
            System.out.println(question3[rq]);
            ra=r.nextInt(4);
            if(ra==0)
            {
                System.out.println(answer3[rq]);
                for(int i=0;i<3;i++)
                System.out.println(options3[r.nextInt(len3)]);
                ans=1;
            }
            if(ra==1)
            {
                System.out.println(options3[r.nextInt(len3)]);
                System.out.println(answer3[rq]);
                for(int i=0;i<2;i++)
                System.out.println(options3[r.nextInt(len3)]);
                ans=2;
            }
            if(ra==2)
            {
                for(int i=0;i<2;i++)
                System.out.println(options3[r.nextInt(len3)]);
                System.out.println(answer3[rq]);
                System.out.println(options3[r.nextInt(len3)]);
                ans=3;
            }
            if(ra==3)
            {
                for(int i=0;i<3;i++)
                System.out.println(options3[r.nextInt(len3)]);
                System.out.println(answer3[rq]);
                ans=4;
            }   

        }
        if(qch==3)
        {
            rq=r.nextInt(4);
            System.out.println(question4[rq]);
            ra=r.nextInt(4);
            if(ra==0)
            {
                System.out.println(answer4[rq]);
                for(int i=0;i<3;i++)
                System.out.println(options4[r.nextInt(len4)]);
                ans=1;
            }
            if(ra==1)
            {
                System.out.println(options4[r.nextInt(len4)]);
                System.out.println(answer4[rq]);
                for(int i=0;i<2;i++)
                System.out.println(options4[r.nextInt(len4)]);
                ans=2;
            }
            if(ra==2)
            {
                for(int i=0;i<2;i++)
                System.out.println(options4[r.nextInt(len4)]);
                System.out.println(answer4[rq]);
                System.out.println(options4[r.nextInt(len4)]);
                ans=3;
            }
            if(ra==3)
            {
                for(int i=0;i<3;i++)
                System.out.println(options4[r.nextInt(len4)]);
                System.out.println(answer4[rq]);
                ans=4;
            }   

        }


        //The Scanner to get input from the user
        //Made a second scanner to save as the answer from the user
        Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
        int uans;
        System.out.println("\n\t\tenter your answer 1,2,3,4");
        System.out.println("\n\t\tif you want to quit enter 5");
        uans=sc.nextInt();
        if(uans==ans)
        {
            System.out.println("\n\t\t\tCorrect answer\n");
            nextq=1;m++;bal++;

            //if they won the whole game this is printed out
            if(m==14)
            {
                System.out.println("\nCongrats\t\tCongrats");
                System.out.println("\n\t\t You Won A $" + m);
                System.out.println("\nCongrats\t\tCongrats");
            }
        }

        // if the user chose to quit the game this is printed
        else if(uans==5)
        {
            System.out.println("\t\t\tYou have chose to quit the game");
            System.out.println(com2[r.nextInt(4)]);
            System.out.print("\t\tThe answer to the question was ");
            if(qch==0)
                System.out.println("option "+ans+" "+answer1[rq]);
            if(qch==1)
                System.out.println("option "+ans+" "+answer2[rq]);
            if(qch==2)
                System.out.println("option "+ans+" "+answer3[rq]);
            nextq=0;
            if(qch==3)
                System.out.println("option "+ans+" "+answer4[rq]);
            nextq=0;
        }

        //if the user chose the wrong answer to the Question this is printed
        else
        {
            nextq=0;
            System.out.println("\n\t Sorry that is the wrong answer");
            System.out.print("\t\tThe answer to the question was ");
            if(qch==0)
                System.out.println("option "+ans+" "+answer1[rq]);
            if(qch==1)
                System.out.println("option "+ans+" "+answer2[rq]);
            if(qch==2)
                System.out.println("option "+ans+" "+answer3[rq]);
            nextq=0;
            if(qch==3)
                System.out.println("option "+ans+" "+answer4[rq]);
            nextq=0;
            System.out.print("\t\t\t You have won $");

            //Checks how much money the user already has then prints out how much they won
            if((money[bal]<10000)&&(money[bal]>=0))
            System.out.println("0");
            if((money[bal]<320000)&&(money[bal]>=10000))
            System.out.println("10000");
            if((money[bal]<10000000)&&(money[bal]>=320000))
            System.out.println("320000");
        }
        if(nextq==1)
            System.out.println(com1[r.nextInt(4)]);
        }while(nextq==1);
    }

}
```

Comment: you should store asked questions in different data structure(array) and check that your random number not in that.

Comment: Also, you have a typo here: `Let the games being computer first question please.` ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option for this sort of thing is to create a `List` containing all your questions, randomly shuffle it using `Collections.shuffle()` and then create a Queue from it. Then you can just pop questions off your queue, and you'll never repeat a question. Probably easier than keeping track of which questions have been asked.

Here's an example of doing this with a simple list of integers:

```
package test;

import java.util.ArrayDeque;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Queue;



public class Test {

  public static void main(String[] argv) {
    List<Integer> intList = Arrays.asList(1,2,3,4,5);
    Collections.shuffle(intList);
    Queue<Integer> intQueue = new ArrayDeque<Integer>(intList);
    Integer x;
    while ((x = intQueue.poll()) != null) {
      System.out.println(x);
    }
  }

}
```

Comment: 1 up for Collections.shuffle() exactly what I try to do

Answer (score 0):

Keep track of which questions have been asked already in an `ArrayList` (alternatively, you can use any kind of storage method available to you), and check that list to see if the question you're about to ask has been asked before. If so, ask a different question. Otherwise, ask the question.

---

I'm not going to debug that massive code dump for you, and I doubt many of us will. Please read [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to improve your chances at having a better answer.

Comment: Alternatively OP could store the answers in an `ArrayList` to begin with and just remove questions as they're asked. Though it looks like this may be an entry level course assignment without having had introductions to `ArrayList`

Comment: @Trobbins It's exactly because it looks like a course assignment, and that it's just a code dump, that I've only provided a  possible option instead of actual code.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use random number at the time when 1st question asked. Generates list of random number in which questions will asked before ask any questions.

Use LinkedHashSet that maintains Random sequence and uniqueness also.

```
Set<Integer> generated = new
LinkedHashSet<Integer>();
while (generated.size() < numbersNeeded)
    {
        Integer next = rng.nextInt(max) + 1;
        generated.add(next);
    }
```